# Moving faces radially

Tags: mesh

I would like to move faces radially, but for some reason they don't want that.
When I move the faces, I expected them relatively to the middle / radially.
But as one can see from the screenshot, they move... ermhhh, differently.
One the face with the white circle moves as I expected.

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to achieve a radial movement?

Comment: in object mode have you applied scale and rotation? (Ctrl+A)

Comment: related? : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21688/error-extruding-loop-selection-along-individual-face-normals/21694#21694

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Ensure that the Pivot Point is set to '3D Cursor'.
- In edit mode, select the faces you want to move radially.
- Hit 'Shift-S', then select 'Cursor to Selected'. The 3D Cursor should now be in the center of your selected faces.
- Hit 'S' then 'Shift+Z'. This will scale your faces in X and Y but not Z.
- Move your mouse or enter a value from the keyboard and hit enter when the faces have been moved radially to the correct position.

Comment: Can you also tell me how this would work for rotating the faces shown in the screenshots? I would like to have the facing downwards, but that gives me the same problems as my initial problem, but 'R' then Shift+Z won't fix it for me.

Comment: You may want to ask a separate question for this, but... Enter edge mode, select just the top edges of those faces you want to face downward. Then hit Shift+S, Cursor to Selected, then 'S' and move your mouse. Should work.

Answer (score 2):

Shrink Fatten.  Keyboard Alt-S.  Move Selected vertices along the geometric surface normal.

---

You're looking for **Shrink/Fatten** operation. This will move selected faces or vertices along their own surface normals.

To do so, select your faces or vertices and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: If you leave my original text unaltered first you are welcome to add your verbiage after mine.   10 sentence maximum, since I see 5 bullet points in another response.  Then I can see how your verbiage has some value in this somewhat uncomplicated request from the original poster of the question.   There is the official invitation. @Polosson

Comment: done. It's not highly relevant modification, but tries to be more human readable. Without wanting to be unkind, of course. Cheers!

Comment: What an amazing improvement!  I am staggered and textless.

Comment: Thank you, that does what I want in this special case, but I would like a more generic approach, thus I think I will try out the 3D cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to scale them with the pivot point set to the object's center?

If this causes them to move in the Z direction you have two alternatives to compensate:

1. <kbd>g z</kbd> to adjust their position afterward.
2. use the 3D cursor as a pivot point after you copy it from the object origin, and then adjust its Z before scaling the faces.