# Ways to create a cylindrical shell (annular volume)?

Tags: mesh, geometry

The only way I know how to make a cylindrical shell is to

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, Cylinder, to insert a cylindrical mesh.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, Cylinder, to insert another cylindrical mesh.
3. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, to double the height of the second cylinder.
4. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift+Z</kbd><kbd>0.5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, to halve the diameter of the second cylinder.
5. <kbd>Right Click</kbd> the first cylinder, click the wrench icon, Add Modifier, Boolean, Difference, Cylinder 001 (or whatever the skinny cylinder's name is), Apply.
6. <kbd>Right Click</kbd> the second cylinder, <kbd>x</kbd> to delete it.

[image: Created cylindrical shell (annular volume)]

Does anyone know easier ways of making a cylindrical shell, preferably out of a single circular mesh or cylinder?

Comment: What about the *solidify* modifier? Or *E > Esc > Alt S*?

Comment: Sort of related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7365/599

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Add a cylinder. (with cap fill set to *Nothing*)
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode.
3. <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

<kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the cylinder, then <kbd>S</kbd> to scale the newly created cylinder and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the scaling to only the X and Y axis.

[image: animated gif]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution, but Where do I set "cap fill" to "nothing"?

Comment: The operator properties are shown at the bottom of the toolbar (a little + will be shown if it is hidden there) or they can be shown in a floating panel by pressing F6

Comment: @user1717828 right after you added a mesh object you will find those options in the 3D View Tool Shelf (T). Just make sure you don't switch modes or deselect the object before changing those options.

Comment: @user1717828 If you have not already found the options, [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23037/2217) question should help.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a cylinder and apply a solidify modifier..
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another method using curves:

Add two **Bezier Circles** and select one. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into **Edit Mode** and with all handles selected press <kbd>V</kbd> and select **Vector**. Press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of **Edit Mode** and select the other circle. In the properties panel (Data) set the other curve as **Bevel Object**.

The shape can be adjusted by scaling the bevel object in object mode or moving the handles in **Edit Mode**. You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to convert the curve into a mesh.

[image]

Or using the Screw Modifier:

You can also use the **Screw Modifier**. Add a plane, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into **Edit Mode**. With all vertices selected press <kbd>X</kbd> - Only Faces. Move the vertices off center along the Y axis. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of Edit Mode and add a Screw Modifier. Select the X axis.

[image]

Both methods are also good for more complex geometry.