# Extrude multiple edges with normals

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, edges, extrude

I have the following problem:
I have walls with (wood) panels. I want to (extrude?) the blue edges so they look like the red marked one... 
When I select all the edges and extrude & scale them, then they will also be scaled on "the wrong axis"...
I'm very new to Blender and have no idea how to do that... a keyword would propably do it, because english is not my first language and i don't quite know how to express myself...
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Select your loops
2. Press 'Spacebar'
3. Type in: Extrude and Move on Indiviual Normals

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While scaling, you can press x, y, or z to restrict the scaling action to only one axis. You can also press shift x, shift y, or shift z to exclude an axis from the scale action.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make your normal consist and recalculate normals. While in Edit mode, select all, press Ctrl+N (will make normals consistent), Press T, for left panel, under Shading>Normals>recalculate normals