# Why there is gap between 2 face

Tags: mesh

I have made triangular face and extrude and then array. With extrude face i have added a loopcut. I want to extrude the top part but when i extrude there is a gap between the corner of the edges. I apply rotation scale yet same problem. May i know the reason why there is gap and why its not extruded in same shape.

[image]

[image]

Gap between

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to extrude in Vertex Select Mode as opposed to Face Select Mode?

Comment: @Dontwalk yeah i tried vertex, edge and face same result

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7365/599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason there is a gap is because when you use a modifier, the mesh editor is not aware of the other faces, and therefore they are not joined. As a result the face will behave like it is not connected. To get the behavior you desire, you will need to extrude by scaling.

1. Select the vertex at the center of your mesh
2. hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>>*Cursor to selected*
3. Set the pivot point to 3D cursor. (<kbd>.</kbd>)
4. Hit <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, then S to scale, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop it from expanding vertically. Scale to taste.

Gif:

[image]

*Note: There will be interior faces on the sides of your new extrusion, it would probably be best to remove them.*