# How to snake extrude in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude

I want to extruding edge/faces with flow movement using my drawing tablet instead of extruding with ctrl+RMB or rapidly type E
[image]
is there any solution how to do this? (with or without addon)

Comment: you can extrude them along normals via ALT+E

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extrude Faces along Local Normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7365/extrude-faces-along-local-normals)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way (as per my limited understanding). But in your case, I think to simplify the mouseclicks (without having to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>), you can select an edge or a face, and Select the Extrude to Cursor (same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**RMB**), and **just click away** :)

[image: extrude to cursor tool]

Like this (I'm not pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**RMB**)

[image: Selection preview]